# Remove keydown/keyup document.eventListener when element is deleted

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onkeydown, onkeyup, removeeventlistener

I have a div with id "div1" that gets updated when the user presses keys.  I have added an eventlistener for the keydown event that runs a function "update" and attached it **to the document** as follows:

```
let div=document.getElementById("div1");
document.addEventListener("keydown",update);
div.remove()
//event listener remains listening, because it's attached to document
```

When "div1" is removed from the DOM, the event listener remains.  If I added the event listener to "div1", then the event listener would be removed when div1 is removed from the DOM.

```
let div=document.getElementById("div1");
div.addEventListener("keydown",update);
div.remove()
//event listener removed, no more listening
```

This approach doesn't work however, since the element has to be focused for the keydown event to trigger and my div1 doesn't have focus and I want the user to be able to update without clicking on the item anyway.

Is there a way to automatically remove the event listener when the element is deleted (as in case 2) even though the event listener is attached to the document (as in case 1).  Alternatively, is there another alternative for attaching the event listener to the element and still listening for all keydown events.

Comment: Either manually remove the listener, or don't remove it at all and use event delegation.

Comment: I probably need to update my question, but here is what I was messing around with: https://jsfiddle.net/c92tmgpr/

Comment: In case #1 above the eventListener will still trigger the update function whenever the document receives a keydown event (as expected).  That is why I say the eventListener still remains.

Comment: I am seeing that exact behavior you describe.  I was just wondering if there was some way to tie keydownFunction2 to div test2, so that when test2 is removed, the listener is also removed (even though it is attached to the document).

Comment: I definitely realize there are many other solutions to this problem, but just thought it would make things very clean if there is a way to do this that I am missing.

Comment: **Sorry**, I completely misunderstood the question to start with!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more passive way than using the MutationObserver (element will only be removed the first time the event is fired after removal, rather than when the element is removed):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",update);

function update(){
  let div=document.getElementById("div1");
  if(div===null || div.isConnected===false){//div1 is currently not attached to DOM
    document.removeEventListener("keydown",update);
    return;  
  }
  //other update code here
}
```

Comment: Good alternative!

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation. Then you can check the event target in the callback to see if it matches the removed element so you can unbind the event listener.

```
 let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    parent.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      let target = event.target;
      if (target.id === "div1") {
        update();
        parent.removeEventListener("keydown", arguments.callee);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that event listener with a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) observing changes to `div1`'s parent element and looking to see if `div1` was removed by the change:

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

// Add the handler
let handler = (event) => {
    console.log(`key pressed: ${event.key}`);
};
document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);

// Watch for changes to the parent of the div
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
    // If `div1` is done, remove the event handler and
    // stop listening for changes.
    // You could use `mutationList` here if you liked rather than
    // doing getElementById
    if (!document.getElementById("div1")) {
        console.log("div1 is gone, removing handler and mutation observer");
        div = null; // Not necessary, but probably good
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
        observer.disconnect();
        handler = null; // Not necessary, but probably good
    }
});
observer.observe(div1.parentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });

// Just a way to remove the div
document.querySelector("input[value='Remove div1']").addEventListener("click", () => {
    div1.remove();
    div1 = null;
});
```

```html
<div id="div1">This is div1</div>
<input type="button" value="Remove div1">
```